# Perl lookup data in hashs table faster

Tags: performance, perl

I use code like this to find data values for my calculations:

```
 sub get_data {
 $x =0 if($_[1] eq "A"); #get column number by name
 $data{'A'}= [2.00000, 0.15000, -0.00143, 33.51030, 0.77, 1, 0, 12];
 return $data{$_[0]}[$x];
 }
```

Data is stored like this in Perl file. I plan no more than 100 columns. Then to get value I call:

```
    get_data(column, row);
```

Now I realized that that is terribly slow way to look up data in table. How can I do it faster? SQL?

Comment: If you want to do it in SQL, then check out DBI module.

Comment: You call the function with `column, row`, but then test the second argument to be the `column`?

Comment: I Answered questions in comments with edits. mpapec, ups fixed.

Comment: Have you profiled your code?  Are you sure that the `get_data` function is slow?

Comment: Why do you believe this to be "terribly slow"? Hash lookups are actually pretty fast. Much faster than making a call to an SQL database, especially if that database is on disk.

Comment: You can find all code here: https://github.com/ProzacR/VR_score Maybe it is as fast as it could be with so many calculations.

Comment: Your github link is broken.

Comment: It's not a "terribly slow" way to look up data.  If your program is slow then the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your github code, the main problem you have is that your 
big hash of arrays is initialized every time the function is called.

Your current code:

```
my @atom;
# {'name'}= radius, depth, solvation_parameter, volume, covalent_radius, hydrophobic, H_acceptor, MW
$atom{'C'}= [2.00000, 0.15000, -0.00143, 33.51030, 0.77, 1, 0, 12];
$atom{'A'}= [2.00000, 0.15000, -0.00052, 33.51030, 0.77, 0, 0, ''];
$atom{'N'}= [1.75000, 0.16000, -0.00162, 22.44930, 0.75, 0, 1, 14];
$atom{'O'}= [1.60000, 0.20000, -0.00251, 17.15730, 0.73, 0, 1, 16];
...
```

Time taken for your test case on the slow netbook I'm typing this on: 6m24.400s.

The most important thing to do is to move this out of the function, so it's
initialized only once, when the module is loaded.

Time taken after this simple change: 1m20.714s.

But since I'm making suggestions, you could write it more legibly:

```
my %atom = (
  C => [ 2.00000, 0.15000, -0.00143, 33.51030, 0.77, 1, 0, 12 ],
  A => [ 2.00000, 0.15000, -0.00052, 33.51030, 0.77, 0, 0, '' ],
  ...
);
```

Note that %atom is a hash in both cases, so your code doesn't do what you
were imagining: it declares a lexically-scoped array @atom, which is unused, then proceeds to fill up an unrelated global variable %atom.  (Also do you really want an empty string for MW of A?  And what kind of atom is A anyway?)

Secondly, your name-to-array-index mapping is also slow.  Current code:

```
#take correct value from data table
$x = 0 if($_[1] eq "radius");
$x = 1 if($_[1] eq "depth");
$x = 2 if($_[1] eq "solvation_parameter");
$x = 3 if($_[1] eq "volume");
$x = 4 if($_[1] eq "covalent_radius");
$x = 5 if($_[1] eq "hydrophobic");
$x = 6 if($_[1] eq "H_acceptor");
$x = 7 if($_[1] eq "MW");
```

This is much better done as a hash (again, initialized outside the function):

```
my %index = (
  radius              => 0,
  depth               => 1,
  solvation_parameter => 2,
  volume              => 3,
  covalent_radius     => 4,
  hydrophobic         => 5,
  H_acceptor          => 6,
  MW                  => 7
);
```

Or you could be snazzy if you wanted:

```
my %index = map { [qw[radius depth solvation_parameter volume
                      covalent_radius hydrophobic H_acceptor MW
                     ]]->[$_] => $_ } 0..7;
```

Either way, the code inside the function is then simply:

```
$x = $index{$_[1]};
```

Time now: 1m13.449s.

Another approach is just to define your field numbers as constants.
Constants are capitalized by convention:

```
use constant RADIUS=>0, DEPTH=>1, ...;
```

Then the code in the function is

```
$x = $_[1];
```

and you then need to call the function using the constants instead of strings:

```
get_atom_parameter('C', RADIUS);
```

I haven't tried this.

But stepping back a bit and looking at how you are using this function:

```
while($ligand_atom[$x]{'atom_type'}[0]) {
 print STDERR $ligand_atom[$x]{'atom_type'}[0];
 $y=0;
 while($protein_atom[$y]) {
 $d[$x][$y] = sqrt(distance_sqared($ligand_atom[$x],$protein_atom[$y]))
 - get_atom_parameter::get_atom_parameter($ligand_atom[$x]{'atom_type'}[0], 'radius');
 - get_atom_parameter::get_atom_parameter($protein_atom[$y]{'atom_type'}[0], 'radius');
 $y++;
 }
$x++;
print STDERR ".";
}
```

Each time through the loop you are calling `get_atom_parameter` twice to
retrieve the radius.
But for the inner loop, one atom is constant throughout.  So hoist the call
to `get_atom_parameter` out of the inner loop, and you've almost halved the
number of calls:

```
while($ligand_atom[$x]{'atom_type'}[0]) {                                       
 print STDERR $ligand_atom[$x]{'atom_type'}[0];                                 
 $y=0;                                                                          
 my $lig_radius = get_atom_parameter::get_atom_parameter($ligand_atom[$x]{'atom_type'}[0], 'radius');                                                               

 while($protein_atom[$y]) {                                                     
 $d[$x][$y] = sqrt(distance_sqared($ligand_atom[$x],$protein_atom[$y]))         
 - $lig_radius
 - get_atom_parameter::get_atom_parameter($protein_atom[$y]{'atom_type'}[0], 'radius');
 $y++;
 }
$x++;
print STDERR ".";
}
```

But there's more.  In your test case the ligand has 35 atoms and the
protein 4128 atoms.  This means that your initial code made
4128*35*2 = 288960 calls to `get_atom_parameter`, and while now it's
only 4128*35 + 35 = 144515 calls, it's easy to just make some arrays with
the radii so that it's only 4128 + 35 = 4163 calls:

```
my $protein_size = $#protein_atom;
my $ligand_size;
{                                                                               
  my $x=0;                                                                      
  $x++ while($ligand_atom[$x]{'atom_type'}[0]);                                 
  $ligand_size = $x-1;                                                          
}
#print STDERR "protein_size = $protein_size, ligand_size = $ligand_size\n";
my @protein_radius;
for my $y (0..$protein_size) {
  $protein_radius[$y] = get_atom_parameter::get_atom_parameter($protein_atom[$y]{'atom_type'}[0], 'radius');
}                                                                               

my @lig_radius;
for my $x (0..$ligand_size) {
  $lig_radius[$x] = get_atom_parameter::get_atom_parameter($ligand_atom[$x]{'atom_type'}[0], 'radius');
}                                                                               

for my $x (0..$ligand_size) {
 print STDERR $ligand_atom[$x]{'atom_type'}[0];
 my $lig_radius = $lig_radius[$x];
 for my $y (0..$protein_size) {
 $d[$x][$y] = sqrt(distance_sqared($ligand_atom[$x],$protein_atom[$y]))
 - $lig_radius
 - $protein_radius[$y]
 }
print STDERR ".";
}
```

And finally, the call to `distance_sqared` [sic]:

```
#distance between atoms
sub distance_sqared {
my $dxs = ($_[0]{'x'}-$_[1]{'x'})**2;
my $dys = ($_[0]{'y'}-$_[1]{'y'})**2;
my $dzs = ($_[0]{'z'}-$_[1]{'z'})**2;
return $dxs+$dys+$dzs;
}
```

This function can usefully be replaced with the following, which uses
multiplication instead of **.

```
sub distance_sqared {                                                       
my $dxs = ($_[0]{'x'}-$_[1]{'x'});                                          
my $dys = ($_[0]{'y'}-$_[1]{'y'});                                          
my $dzs = ($_[0]{'z'}-$_[1]{'z'});                                          
return $dxs*$dxs+$dys*$dys+$dzs*$dzs;                                       
}
```

Time after all these modifications: 0m53.639s.

More about **: elsewhere you declare

```
use constant e_math => 2.71828;
```

and use it thus:

```
$Gauss1 += e_math ** (-(($d[$x][$y]*2)**2));
```

The built-in function `exp()` calculates this for you (in fact, ** is commonly
implemented as `x**y = exp(log(x)*y)`, so each time you are doing this you are
performing an unnecessary logarithm the result of which is just slightly less
than 1 as your constant is only accurate to 6 d.p.).  This change would alter
the output very slightly.  And again, **2 should be replaced by multiplication.

Anyway, this answer is probably long enough for now, and calculation of `d[]`
is no longer the bottleneck it was.

Summary: hoist constant values out of loops and functions!  Calculating the
same thing repeatedly is no fun at all.

Using any kind of database for this would not help your performance in the
slightest.  One thing that might help you though is `Inline::C`.  Perl is
not really built for this kind of intensive computation, and Inline::C 
would allow you to easily move performance-critical bits into C while
keeping your existing I/O in Perl.

I would be willing to take a shot at a partial C port.  How stable
is this code, and how fast do you want it to be? :)

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in a DB will make it MUCH easier to maintain, scale, expand, etc.... Using a DB can also save you a lot of RAM -- it gets and stores in RAM only the desired result instead of storing ALL values.

With regards to speed it depends. With a text file you take a long time to read all the values into RAM, but once it is loaded, retrieving the values is super fast, faster than querying a DB.

So it depends on how your program is written and what it is for. Do you read all the values ONCE and then run 1000 queries? The TXT file way is probably faster. Do you read all the values every time you make a query (to make sure you have the latest value set) -- then the DB would be faster. Do you 1 query/day? use a DB. etc......